# How to conver date on arguments into format date yyMMdd

Tags: java, date

I want to save the console into .txt like this

[image: Data_Bank_yyMMdd.txt]

every time i run the app.

Here's how I use for saving the console based on the current time:

```
SimpleDateFormat dtf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
Date date = new Date();

System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("Data_Bank_" + dtf.format(date) + ".txt")));
```

However, when I put the run configuration arguments with

[image: 2020-01-24]

I want it to automatically formatted into yyMMdd too. Not like

[image: this (the first one)]

Does anyone know how to do that???? Thanks anyway..

Comment: If you're using Java 8 or above, you can use `LocalDate`. Do you?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Wekcome to Stack Overflow. Your question leaves me with only little idea which part you are missing. Is this a question about reading command line arguments? Changing date format? Creating a file with a specific name? Please narrow your question considerably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have input date i will parse the date and do something like this and save that for file,

```
    String input = "Thu Jun 18 20:56:02 EDT 2009";
    SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
    Date date = parser.parse(input);
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
    String formattedDate = formatter.format(date);
    .......
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("Data_Bank_"+formattedDate +".txt")));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use Java 8 or higher, then it's recommended to use **[`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)** for operations with dates and times.

You can solve your problem with `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // get the date of today
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    // and parse a given date with a 
    LocalDate someDate = LocalDate.parse("2020-01-24");

    // define a formatter using your desired date pattern
    DateTimeFormatter dtfShort = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyMMdd");

    // print the dates using a built-in formatter
    System.out.println("[ISO]\t" + today.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
                    + "\t" + someDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE));
    // print the dates using your custom formatter
    System.out.println("[Short]\t" + today.format(dtfShort)
                    + "\t\t" + someDate.format(dtfShort));
}
```

The output is this:

```
[ISO]   2020-01-22  2020-01-24
[Short] 200122      200124
```

Should be easy to use for file output, which should be done with **[`java.nio`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html)** nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to parse the String that you're passing as an argument. You're on the right track with `SimpleDateFormat`. You just need to parse the input and then convert it to the format you're looking for using the `parse` method on the `SimpleDateFormat`

Something like:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date inputDate = input.parse(args[0]);
            SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");

            System.out.println(output.format(inputDate));
        }catch(ParseException parseException) {
            //handle error
            parseException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The java docs on date parsing are pretty good. Read more here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Dates get complex quickly in Java. Learn more about options in Java 8 and `LocalDate` here:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro

https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-to-date

Comment: it went like this..
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 input cannot be resolved to a type

 at com.jalin.common.App.main(App.java:34)

Answer (score 0):

The java.time framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes such as java.util.Date, Calendar, & SimpleDateFormat
You may google examples on how to use them, better to use the latest classes